# ASP MVC 4 e WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, web-service, visual-studio-2013

Possuo um WebService com todos os métodos que preciso para fazer o sistema funcionar e também tenho uma página `ASP NET MVC 4`. Já fiz a referencia no services references do WebService.
Consigo acessar um método que retorna uma string simples, mas quando chamo um metodo do WebService que faz requisição para o banco de dados(inserir) ele me retorna um erro:
`System.Data.EntityException: O provedor subjacente falhou em Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Falha de logon do usuário 'IIS APPPOOL\\ApPizza'.\n   em System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnE...`. Pesquisei e encontrei algo como isto: não está fazendo o impersonate do usuário do IIS.

Queria saber se há alguma configuração que devo fazer. Tanto no Web.Config quanto no projeto todo.

Comment: Tem como você passar sua ConnectionString ?

Comment: A minha connectionString esta no WebService que está hospedado no IIS

Comment: Se você não passar as configurações e como está seu projeto Web Service fica dificil opinar !!!

Answer (score 1):

- Entre no SQL Server Management Studio;
- Faça o login no seu servidor;
- Vá na pasta <kbd>Segurança</kbd> > <kbd>Logons</kbd>;
- Botão Direito > <kbd>Novo Logon</kbd>;
- Em Nome de Login, clique em <kbd>Pesquisar</kbd>;
- Digite `IIS APPPOOL\ApPizza` e clique em <kbd>Ok</kbd>;
- Clique em `Mapeamentos de Usuário` e defina as permissões de base;
- Clique em <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Comment: No SQL Server Managemant Studio na pasta segurança tem Logons. Tentamos fazer o que você disse e retornou um erro: Não foi possivel localizar um objeto (Usuario ou Entidade de segurança interna) denonominado "ISS APPPOOL\\ApPizza"

Comment: @ThiagoAlex, Teste cadastrando outro usuário no `SQL Server`, depois informe ele na sua `connectionString` com o `User Id` e `Password`.

Comment: @ThiagoAlex Você está certo. Passei alguns passos errados. Editei a resposta. Experimente localizar o usuário com uma barra só. Deve funcionar agora.